# Using Threading Building Blocks with ROS

Tags: rosdep, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I couldn't find any information about how to use ROS with Threading Building Blocks (TBB). If I add

```
<rosdep name="tbb" />
```

to my manifest.xml and do "rosdep install" I get the error "Failed to find rosdep tbb for package ... on OS:ubuntu version:natty". Do I have to create my own rosdep.yaml file? I'm working with ROS Electric on Ubuntu Natty.

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38106/using-threading-building-blocks-with-ros/) by [christiank](https://answers.ros.org/users/1553/christiank/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2012-07-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is confusing, because `rosdep` changed significantly between Electric and Fuerte.

- On Fuerte it resolves to `libtbb-dev`.
- On Electric, it needs to be defined in some stack's rosdep.yaml.

What does this show?

```
$ rosdep where_defined tbb
```

UPDATE: your result shows that `tbb` is not defined by any stack in your `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`.

If you are developing a stack of your own, add a `rosdep.yaml` containing something like this stanza:

```
tbb:
  arch: intel-tbb
  ubuntu: libtbb-dev
  fedora: tbb-devel
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [christiank](https://answers.ros.org/users/1553/christiank/) on 2012-07-08**:
the output is:

```
$ rosdep where_defined tbb
tbb defined in set([])
```

**Comment by [christiank](https://answers.ros.org/users/1553/christiank/) on 2012-07-09**:
thanks, this works :)

Finally, I had to add a command to link against tbb to my CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_link_libraries(mynode tbb)
```